# Extra character in row

Tags: powershell, character, extra

Why does this code place [] or similar in the second column at the bottom of resulting output?

```
$objs = @();
$output = Import-Csv -Path "c:\users\patrick\desktop\RelayGroups\file2concatenate.csv" | ForEach {
    $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{           
        unique_sis_group_id  = [String]::Concat($_.unique_sis_group_id, $_.course)
        group_name           = $_.section
        unique_sis_user_id   = $_.unique_sis_user_id
        unique_sis_school_id = $_.unique_sis_school_id 
    }
    $objs += $Object;
}
$objs
$objs | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\users\patrick\desktop\RelayGroups\groups.csv
```

[image]

Comment: I would examine your source file at this point. Some hidden characters _appear_ to be hiding.

Comment: That character seems to be `� U+FFFD Replacement Character` (displayed as _squared question mark_ in some fonts). Follow @Matt's comment; [edit] the question and add last two lines (incl. seemingly empty ones) from the file (copy&paste _text_, no pictures please).

Comment: 10721 H324405 HBHS *Pre-Calculus Algebra (W)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the symbol in your output because your .csv file contains a Unicode character that the `[String]::Concat()` is concatenating and including in the `unique_sis_group_id` property.

I like to use Notepad++ to view (and if needed cleanup) my flat files before I import them.
Open the file in Notepad++, and open the Encoding menu. My csv file is encoded in UTF-8, and I have inserted a Unicode character (U+08FE in this example)

[image: Notepad++ encoding menu]

When I run the powershell, I can see the Unicode character after the `*Pre-Calculus Algebra (W)`

[image]

You could just delete the character in Notepad++ and run your Powershell, or if you find that the source of this CSV consistently inserts this special character every time it generates the .csv then you can use `-replace` to remove the character from your file before you `Import-Csv` There is a good example of how to do that on the LazyWinAdmin blog [here](https://lazywinadmin.com/2015/08/powershell-remove-special-characters.html).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you gentlemen!